# Phone Gap IOS project not running

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am new to phonegap and developing a application in ios using phonegap. I am using xcode 5 which was upgraded from xcode 4 .I am using phonegap 3.4 . The problem is the project created with phonegap when run in xcode 5 is succedded in building but the while running in the simulator,the splash screen is coming but stopped there due to error as below

```
 Thread 1:signal SIGABRT 
 NSUnknownKeyValueException
```

Comment: post full of error trace log

Comment: @iDev 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttonOfFirstView.' was only error in the log .

Comment: post your code where this error happen with help of breaking point

Comment: Code cannot be pasted , it happens in @autoReleasePoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some files were missing in the project . So the error came. After re-installing phonegap and xcode , it run perfectly

The thread:1 signal sigabrt comes when ever ios application crashes due to any problem.